# jQuery flexslider - getting selected image

Tags: jquery, flexslider, magento-1.9

I am using jQuery flexslider on a home page (at a time 6 thumbnails are displaying. There are around 26 images). After clicked on any image from slider, page reloads and information of that image is displayed in the body.
Basically, All images are products and after selecting any product, page reloads and that product's page appears. Every Product's page also contains same jQuery slider.

My problem is, when product page reloads, then jQuery slider should slide to the currently selected product image, but slider only shows first few images in slider.(i.e. Slider only shows first 6 thumbnails.. It should slide to the selected product image)

Your help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: you can use the startAt option when declaring your slider to start at different slides. So to start at slide 5 use:  $('.flexslider').flexslider({startAt:5});

Comment: thank you @user3473534 .. Actually flexslider object was not available.. I used setTimeout(). Now it is pointing correct slide but after that left and right arrows from flexslider are not responding.